# AJAX result does not show up using HTTPS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My website is www.yourentacar.co.uk
when I navigate to the website using http

1. http://www.yourentacar.co.uk
2. write any letters in the search box
3. AJAX returns results.

The problem occurs when I navigate to the website using https

1. https://www.yourentacar.co.uk
2. write any letters in the search box
3. the page is frozen and I do not get any result.

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem is normally due to CORS issue, where a page on HTTP is not allowed to make a request to HTTPS unless allowed specifically via 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

If you open console, you might see an error like this
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load [your api including protocol]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin [your domain including protocol] is therefore not allowed access.

You can fix this a few ways.

1. Make your site always run on https
2. Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin on your ajax call to allow non ssl domain to visit it, in your case.. something like header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.yourentacar.co.uk